# Given a Cost Function, C(weights), that depends on expected and network outputs, how is C differentiated with respect to weights?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, calculus

I'm building a Neural Network from scratch that categorizes values of x into 21 possible estimates for sin(x). I plan to use MSE as my loss function.

```
MSE of each minibatch = ||y(x) - a||^2, where y(x) is the vector of network outputs for x-
values in the minibatch. a is the vector of expected outputs that correspond to each x.
```

After finding the loss, the column vector of all weights in the network is recalculated. Column vector of delta w's ~= column vector of partial derivatives of C with respect to each weight.

```
∇C≡(∂C/∂w1,∂C/∂w2...).T and Δw =−η∇C where η is the (positive) learn rate.
```

The problem is, to find the gradient of C, you have to differentiate with respect to each weight. What does *that* function even look like? It's not just the previously stated MSE right?

Any help is appreciated. Also, apologies in advance if this question is misplaced, I wasn't sure if it belonged here or in a math forum.

Thank you.

(I might add that I have tried to find an answer to this online, but few examples exist that either don't use libraries to do the dirty work or present the information clearly.)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a math, not programming question, and therefore it is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html

I had found this a while ago but only now realized it's significance. The link describes δ(j,l) as an intermediary value to arrive at the partial derivative of C with respect to weights. I will post back here with a full answer if the link above answers my question, as I've seen a few posts similar to mine that have yet to be answered.